# Issues Mapping SQL Time Type to Any C# Type

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql

I have a column in my mssql db table called `time` that is of type `time(0)`. It is formatted like `hh:mm:ss`. For example "22:07:08".

In my C# .NET project, I am using a `DataContext` object to connect to my database (I am NOT using Entity Framework). I then have a model class that has properties for all of the columns in the table. One of those properties is `Public Timespan Time {get; set;}`.

I am trying to query for the latest entry in the database with `DataContext.ExecuteQuery`. This works correctly, grabs the latest entry, and populates all fields but the `time` field. I get an `InvalidCastException` when trying to map the SQL `time` column value to the C# property. I have also tried `DateTime` with no luck. I even tried converting it to a string, but I get the error `Cannot convert System.TimeSpan to string`. So, it definitely thinks it is a TimeSpan object, but for some reason something is going wrong.

Example:

```
dbContext.ExecuteQuery<MyModel>(@"SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY date desc, time desc").First();
```

Anyone else ever have this issue?

**TDLR; I can't get my `time(0)` column in my sql db to cast to a C#.net `TimeSpan` (or anything at all)**

**EDIT: Bellow are examples of the table / code I'm writing**

```
------------------------------
| date `date`| time `time(0)`|
------------------------------
|2019-02-14  | 22:07:48      |
------------------------------


USE [database]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
([date],[time])
VALUES (<date, date,>, <time, time(0),>)
GO
```

**C# Model**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
var model = dbContext.ExecuteQuery<TestModel>(@"SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable ORDER BY date desc, time desc").First();
```

Date property gets populated correctly but exception thrown when mapping the `time` column to `time` property.

Comment: Just to clarify, using `public string Time { get; set; }` doesn't work either?

Comment: Although you have already given this information, can you actually paste structure of  the `MyModel` class and your table datatypes. The reasons i ask is this seems a little suspect `Time(0)` should convert to `TimeSpan` so something doesn't seem right

Comment: @MichaelRandall Is on to something - `time` in T-SQL represents the time of day, not a timespan.

Comment: Note : there are other classs you can use from `SqlDbType`  such as `SqlDbType.Time`

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data) says TimeSpan is the correct type for a `time` - "SQL Server data type: time .NET Framework type: System.TimeSpan"

Comment: @ViggoLundén String doesn't work, that's when it complains it can't convert a `TimeSpan` to a `string`.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Updated the question to include the structures.

Comment: You’re using two fields and properties when you actually just need one, DateTime.

Comment: @ViggoLundén I'm working with an existing table I'm not permitted to modify. If I had it my way I'd just be using `DateTime` =_=

Comment: Instead of `select * from...`, did you try `select Date, Time from...` Also, can you post the relevant table DML (create table) and sample data as DDL (insert statements)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I specified the columns I wanted to select in the query to the same result. I have also updated the question to include the an insert script